# html options value with php variable

Tags: php, html

I want put php date variable in html options value tag

this is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456789";
$dbname = "db";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $update = "UPDATE date SET date_end = '$choseMonth'";

            if ($conn->query($update) === TRUE) {}

  }
?>


 <form action="update.php>" method="POST">

        Use month <select name="choseMonth">
 <option value="<?php $today_date = date('Y/m/d')?>">1 month + </option>
            </select>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">    
    </form>
```

This code not work I don't know why .. I need put php variable in options value and I do that .. and when I look in MySql I see only 0000-00-00 I don't see date.

Please if any one can help me with this.

Thx

Comment: you're trying to update your entire database because of a missing `WHERE` clause; unless that's what you want to do but I doubt that. check for errors on the query.

Comment: where is `$choseMonth` that defined? question's unclear in many ways and where `$today_date` is used after and not use a POST array for the `<select>`.

Comment: I know that with WHERE my friend .. I have problem with options value in html tag when I put <?php $today_date = date('Y/m/d'); ?> in MySQl only see 0000-00-00 .  And when I do same things with out OPTIONS VALUE all is ok

Comment: someone gave you an answer now, see that.

Comment: Can anyone write only one line code for put php variable in options value tag 

I mean on  this 
                

`<select name="date"><option value="<?php $todaydate = date('Y/m/d');>">1 Month</option>`


This is ok or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not echoing the variable...just storing something in it.

Do this:

```
 <option value="<?php echo date('Y/m/d'); ?>">1 month + </option>
```

Then access the chosen option using the following:

```
$_POST['choseMonth']
```

Comment: Hmm I  maybe some here is problem I go for check this .. 
Because when I use text input date in MySQL and when UPDATE all is ok .. 
Only not work when I use options value method

Comment: Yes this is help .. I only put variable I am not use echo for show what in value tag in html..

thx friend ..

Comment: If my answer solved your question, mark it as such by licking the check mark under the voting buttons.

Comment: I do that .. thx my dear friend on help .. 

and if you know now how I can add one month on $today_date variable that will save my time

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few things wrong.

First, inside the same folder where the code with the `<form>` tag exists, create a new file with name `update.php` and move all your php code into that.

Then, to fix the errors in your HTML, make the following change to your code,

```
<form action="update.php" method="POST">
```

Notice you had an extra '>' character after "update.php".

Comment: *"Then, to fix the errors in your Javascript"* - I don't see any JS.

Comment: I use only php for now .. and when I make this 

           Date: <input type="text" name="dateEnd" value="<?php echo 
            $date_end;?>"><br>

this is work I can change manual date in text file and when update this in MySQL all is work ..

Only don't want work with OPTIONS VALUE method

Answer (score 0):

Thx Enstage on help ..

guys problem is only in echo.

When I want give some rezult in value in my variable I only save but that is not ok.

I must put echo for show variable

```
<select name="date">
<option value="<?php echo $date_end;?>">1 Month</option>
```

This is ansver